# error 2003 Mysql while executing a query or Error Code: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql

I am a newbie.... I am trying to execute a query. Not posting the Query because it is too big.

```
it is failing with an error 

Error Code: 2003
Can't connect to MySQL server on 10.49.50.23
```

or some times i get the error:

```
Error Code: 2013
Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

These are the timeouts that have st

```
Variable_name               Value   
--------------------------  --------
connect_timeout             10      
delayed_insert_timeout      300     
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    600     
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF     
interactive_timeout         28800   
net_read_timeout            60      
net_write_timeout           60      
slave_net_timeout           3600    
table_lock_wait_timeout     50      
wait_timeout                600
```

can some one help me on this

Comment: Please post a minimal problem.  This query is huge, and few people will have the time to read (or format) it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have formatted it. can you please have a look at it

Comment: Format as code, by adding four or more spaces to each line.  It is still not readable unfortunately.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have removed the code thought it might not help in this case

Comment: This is a bit tough.  If you really need to run that query and its size/cost is causing the drop, then you really only have two options: not run the query, or find a way to make it faster.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thats where i am stuck now. searching for solutions